# Copy certain contents from document to another at specific section

Tags: vba, ms-word, copy, paste

I want to copy a certain section (e.g. subject of the document then main body) to another Word document. The documents have different formatting so I need to copy to a predetermined location in the document.

The code below copies the whole of the source document to the target document.

```vb
Sub CopyPaste()
    Dim Word As New Word.Application
    Dim WordDoc As New Word.Document    'active document
    Dim WordDoc1 As New Word.Document   'document to extract from
    Dim dialogBox As FileDialog
    Set dialogBox = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
    Dim Dest_path As String
    
    dialogBox.AllowMultiSelect = False
    dialogBox.Title = "Select a file to copy from"
    
    'Show the file path and file name
    If dialogBox.Show = -1 Then
        MsgBox "You have selected: " & dialogBox.SelectedItems(1)
    End If
        
    ' Starts extracting from source document
    Set WordDoc1 = Word.Documents.Open(dialogBox.SelectedItems(1), ReadOnly:=True)
    Application.Browser.Target = wdBrowseSection
    For i = 1 To ((WordDoc1.Sections.Count) - 1)
        WordDoc1.Bookmarks("\Section").Range.Copy
    
        'Paste into an active document
        ActiveDocument.Bookmarks("\Section").Range.PasteAndFormat wdFormatOriginalFormatting
        WordDoc.ActiveWindow.Visible = True
        WordDoc1.Close
    Next i
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you're apparently running this from Word with an activedocument, you really don't want any of:

```
Dim Word As New Word.Application
Dim WordDoc As New Word.Document    'active document
Dim WordDoc1 As New Word.Document   'document to extract from
```

since that starts a new Word session and two new empty Word documents before you even get to the dialog.

As for:

```
.Bookmarks("\Section")
```

that only works in code like:

```
Set Rng = ActiveDocument.GoTo(What:=wdGoToSection, Name:=i)
Set Rng = Rng.GoTo(What:=wdGoToBookmark, Name:="\section")
```

Try something along the lines of:

```
Sub Replicate()
Dim DocSrc As Document, RngSrc As Range
Dim DocTgt As Document, RngTgt As Range
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogOpen)
  .AllowMultiSelect = False
  .Title = "Select a file for content replication"
  'Show the file path and file name
  If .Show = -1 Then
    MsgBox "You have selected: " & .SelectedItems(1)
    Set DocSrc = Documents.Open(.SelectedItems(1), ReadOnly:=True, Visible:=False)
  Else: Exit Sub
  End If
End With
Set DocTgt = ActiveDocument
' Starts extracting from source document
For i = 1 To ((DocSrc.Count) - 1)
  Set RngTgt = DocTgt.Sections(i).Range
  RngTgt.End = RngTgt.End - 1
  Set RngSrc = DocSrc.Sections(i).Range
  RngSrc.End = RngSrc.End - 1
  RngTgt.FormattedText = RngSrc.FormattedText
Next i
DocSrc.Close False
End Sub
```