# Copy from one Word document to another without breaking styling

Tags: ms-word

We have two word documents, one that is used for as an order template and another that is our terms and conditions (T&C).

We would like to merge both documents into one without breaking the styling and have not been able to do so even with quite a considerable amount of effort.

Essentially, the T&C document has a bunch custom styles some of which overlap with the default word styles. This means that when copy pasting the T&C document into the order template, the result is a complete mess.

Is there a way of combining the two word files while maintaining the existing format (we would like the T&C to be copied into the Word document and not the other way around).

I have tried using the following Macro (found online) to remove the styles of the T&C document and maintain the format:

```
Sub DirectFormat()
    Dim para As Paragraph
    Dim fnt As Font
    Dim pfmt As ParagraphFormat
    For Each para In ActiveDocument.Paragraphs
        With para
            If .Style <> ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal") Then
                Set fnt = .Style.Font
                Set pfmt = .Style.ParagraphFormat
                .Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Normal")
                .Range.Font = fnt
                .Range.ParagraphFormat = pfmt
            End If
        End With
    Next
End Sub
```

However after running it, the document looks completely different.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest and most effective way is to ensure you don't have conflicting Style definitions and that the Style definitions in the source document, especially, haven't been overridden with direct formatting.

Other than that, instead of using copy/paste for content replication, you might use something like:

```
wdRngTgt.FormattedText = wdRngSrc.FormattedText
```

where wdRngTgt defines the destination range and wdRngSrc defines the source range.

Comment: Are both the `wdRngTgt` and `wdRngSrc` in the same document?

Comment: Clearly, for what you want, they wouldn't be. For a variety of implementations, see for example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64853079/copy-certain-contents-from-document-to-another-at-specific-section, http://www.vbaexpress.com/forum/showthread.php?63001-Copy-amp-paste-from-external-doc-to-activedoc-using-bookmarks&p=381259&viewfull=1#post381259, https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/office/en-US/4cac05fd-f87a-4881-a2f8-81f5fc2a1e41/create-multiple-documents-from-a-template-document?forum=worddev, https://www.msofficeforums.com/128975-post6.html